# Embeded Qr code scanner library android

Tags: android

Could anyone suggest me a good QR code reader to embed this in my app.
I'm searching a library which let me embed the scanner directly in my activity.
And with a good tutorial which explain me how to use it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Zxing is great, but it's hard to embed into your app - it's developers focused more on making usage of their own app from Play Store easier.

There are some other libraries, which wrap Zxing around. I used [this](https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner) one in my recent project. It's really easy to use. Probably you can find all what you need in readme.

Comment: Sorry @Wojciech Januszek how to get the library from the git repository? and how can integrate it with eclipse?

Comment: Maybe it's not the answer you'd like, but if your project is not in advanced development state, I would recommend switching to gradle based application in Android Studio. It makes all dependency management painless - adding this library would be one line.

If you really need to use Eclipse, there is "Download ZIP" button on project page which allows you to download whole repo.

Comment: Sorry but when I've downloaded the whole repo how can i get the library?

Comment: You have source code now. I'm afraid that I can't help you with integrating with Eclipse.

Probably you should add all the modules as Eclipse projects with existing sources, but I'm not sure.

Really, if you only can, switch to Android Studio and Gradle. It would probably be much simpler.

Comment: And in android studio How can i achive it?

Comment: Create a gradle based project: https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/create-project.html and add a dependency to library in build.gradle